# Create multiple text files that follow a pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, csv, text-editors

I want to create hundreds of text files that follow a pattern like this (example):

The book [title] written by [author] is about [description] ...

and the variables will be extracted from a csv file .

How can I do this?

Comment: What name and what content for these files?

Comment: @harrymc The names are not relevant . The content is what I wrote in my question : "The book [title] written by [author] is about [description] ... " .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might produce those texts in Excel, and then you can export each row as a text file in its own. There are multiple approaches to this, the most effective one would be using Excel macros.

1. Load your CSV into excel **(title = col A; author = col B; description = col C;)**
2. Into a new column create a formula with concatenation. **="The book "&"A1& " written by "&B1&" is about "&C1**
3. Copy formula down to all rows, creating your final column
4. Copy your final column and **Special Paste** it into a new workbook. You will paste only text, not the formula.
5. Export excel rows into text files as link below.

See topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files